# Get AWS role name from EC2 instance list using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-ec2

AWS CLI requests "ec2 describe-instances" and "ec2 describe-iam-instance-profile-associations" include instance profile in the "IamInstanceProfile" property.

This includes ARN, for example:

```
arn:aws:iam::123:instance-profile/AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup
```

In such a case the last segment, "AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup" in this example, is the IAM role name. This is also suggested in answers to multiple existing questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69002676/how-to-get-an-aws-roles-friendly-name-from-its-arn
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68347014/is-there-a-way-to-get-name-of-iam-role-attached-to-an-ec2-instance-with-boto3
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70307973/how-to-get-arn-of-an-iam-role
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69002676/how-to-get-an-aws-roles-friendly-name-from-its-arn

But sometimes the ARN in the instance profile will look like this:

```
arn:aws:iam::123:instance-profile/eks-ab13cc88-bc13-13bc-acdc-1234567890ab
```

And the last part is not a role name anymore - actually, it seems to be "Auto Scaling Group name". AWS web interface does show the assigned IAM role in both cases inside the instance properties.

How could the role name be reliably obtained for EC2 instances in all cases using AWS CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to @matsuzine@hachyderm.io  - quoting their response here, will delete if they post themselves.

The EC2 instance profile is a container that holds a role. By default, a role will be created that matches the name of the profile, but they could be different.

I think you need to get the profile name and use it to call `aws iam get-instance-profile --instance-profile-name <value>`. In the response you want `InstanceProfile.Roles[].RoleArn`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-instance-profile.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html